# Need help on using Jersey 2.17 and moxy to handle XML any collection

Tags: jersey, moxy, jaxb2

Jaxb classes (provided, I cannot change them),

FindResponse.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

})
@XmlRootElement(name = "findResponse")
public class FindResponse {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected ListWrapper result;

    public ListWrapper getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(ListWrapper value) {
        this.result = value;
    }

}
```

ListWrapper.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "List", propOrder = {
    "any"
})
public class ListWrapper {

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected java.util.List<Object> any;

    public java.util.List<Object> getAny() {
        if (any == null) {
            any = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.any;
    }
}
```

None of the Jaxb classes wrapped in the ListWrapper class has the @XmlRoolElement annotation (generated from .xsd though, 2000+ classes).

LagInterface.class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "lag.Interface")
public class LagInterface extends AggregationPortAggregationGroup {

    private String objectFullName;
    private String displayedName;
    private String description;
    private Integer lagId;

    ...
}
```

Json resource method

```
@GET
@Path("json/{samoXmlType}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response jsonGetService(
        @PathParam("samoXmlType") String samoXmlType,
        @Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception
{
    LagInterface lag = new LagInterface();
    lag.setObjectFullName("lag-interface:1");
    lag.setDisplayedName("lag 1");
    lag.setDescription("moxy test");
    lag.setLagId(1);

    FindResponse findResponse = new FindResponse();
    ListWrapper result = new ListWrapper();
    result.getAny().addAll(Arrays.asList(lag));
    findResponse.setResult(result);

    return Response.ok(findResponse).build();
}
```

Response from the above method:

```
{"result":{}}
```

The similar XML response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:findResponse xmlns:ns0="xmlapi_1.0"><ns0:result/></ns0:findResponse>
```

This is the warning message related to the XML Any collection:

```
[EL Warning]: XMLAnyCollectionMappingNodeValue: The undefined document root element of a referenced object [XMLDescriptor(LagInterface --> [])] is ignored during marshalling with an any collection|object mapping.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I get it worked by using the oxm metadata file to add the missing @XmlRootElement on LagInterface. But the performance is so bad, it takes a minute to get the xml or json content.

And now I have another issue, in the oxm metadata file, I have to specify the package-name. This means I will have to create quite some oxm files for my JAXB model classes.

Is there a way that I can have one medata file for all my model classes?